# Wrapping highlight question text in Qualtrics?

Tags: html, css, display, word-wrap, qualtrics

I created a survey in Qualtrics and have some "highlight" questions but I can *NOT* get the designated highlight text to wrap. This is problematic because the majority of users will be taking the survey on mobile.  I've tried messing with display, overflow, word-wrap, word-break, span, etc. I don't know if I'm not targeting the right class but I feel like I've tried everything.

I can get the text above the question to wrap but there is something going on with the text that is highlight-able.

Here is a [link to a test survey](https://ufl.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_ePeeTyEjiAE4C5n) I created to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: It wraps for me.  I think you've been looking at a cached version, so it appeared as if nothing changed. Actually, it break words, which you probably don't want.

Comment: It does wrap but the word breaks are what I'm worried about.